# Child is not updated when boolean prop is changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I have the following components:

Parent:

```js
<template>
    <Child path="instance.json" 
             v-bind:authenticated="authenticated" 
             v-bind:authenticator="authenticator" 
    />
</template>

<script>
import { getAuthenticator } from '../auth';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      authenticated: false,
      authenticator: null
    };
  },
  beforeMount: async function () {
    this.authenticator = getAuthenticator()
    this.checkAccess();
  },
  methods: {
    checkAccess() {
      this.authenticated = this.authenticator.isAuthenticated();
    },
    async login() {
      this.checkAccess();
      await this.authenticator.signIn();
      this.checkAccess();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Child:

```js
<template>
  <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
</template>

<script>
import swagger from "swagger-ui-dist";
import "swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css";

export default {
  props: ["path", "authenticated", "authenticator"],
  mounted: async function() {
    if (this.authenticated) {
      let token = (await this.authenticator.getToken()).accessToken;

      const ui = swagger.SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: this.path,
        dom_id: "#swagger-ui",
        onComplete: function() {
          ui.preauthorizeApiKey("token", token);
        }
      });
    } else {
      const ui = swagger.SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: this.path,
        dom_id: "#swagger-ui"
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In the parent component, when the `login` method is called, the `authenticated` variable changes to `true`. Since `authenticated` is passed as a prop to the Child component, I'd expect the Child to be refreshed whenever `authenticated` is changed. However, the Child does not refresh.

I think that the problem might be caused by the fact that I am not using `authenticated` in the template of the child at all. Instead, I'm using it only in the `mounted` hook. In my case, I have no use for `authenticated` in the template.

I tried two solutions:

- calling `this.$forceUpdate()` in the `login` method of Parent - that didn't work at all (nothing changed)
- Adding `:key` to the Child, and changing the key each time the `login` is called - this works, however, it's a bit hacky. I'd like to understand how to do that properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to use a watcher.
Actually, your code is only run once (when de component is mounted), not at each prop change.

```
<template>
  <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
</template>

<script>
import swagger from 'swagger-ui-dist';
import 'swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css';

export default {
  props: {
    path: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    authenticated: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    authenticator: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  watch: {
    async authenticated(newValue) {
      await this.updateSwagger(newValue);
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.updateSwagger(this.authenticated);
  }
  methods: {
    async updateSwagger(authenticated) {
      if (authenticated) {
        const token = (await this.authenticator.getToken()).accessToken;

        const ui = swagger.SwaggerUIBundle({
          url: this.path,
          dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
          onComplete: function () {
            ui.preauthorizeApiKey('token', token);
          },
        });
      } else {
        const ui = swagger.SwaggerUIBundle({
          url: this.path,
          dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        });
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fine that you're not using it in the template, the issue is that you only check `authenticated` in the child's `mounted` hook, which only runs once (and is `false` at that time).

You should use a `watch` to track changes to the `authenticated` prop instead of `mounted`:

```js
watch: {
  authenticated: {
    handler(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.setUi();
    },
    immediate: true   // Run the watch when `authenticated` is first set, too
  }
}
```

That will call a `setUi` method every time `authenticated` changes:

```
methods: {
  async setUi() {
    if (this.authenticated) {
      let token = (await this.authenticator.getToken()).accessToken;

      const ui = swagger.SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: this.path,
        dom_id: "#swagger-ui",
        onComplete: function() {
          ui.preauthorizeApiKey("token", token);
        }
      });
    } else {
      const ui = swagger.SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: this.path,
        dom_id: "#swagger-ui"
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After applying this solution I'm getting an error from swaggerUi about React modification. The answer is very similar to the other one, thanks for your time!

Comment: What's probably happening is the immediate execution of the `watch` happens before the component is `mounted` which creates a problem with your 3rd party library.  Makes sense actually.  In most cases, I would consider this answer the more elegant solution because you don't repeat yourself in `mounted`, but here it's true that the other answer is necessary